# When attempting to decrypt an already encrypted string, no response is given

Tags: php, php-openssl

```php
function encrypt($string, $key)
{
    $method = "BF-CBC";
    $iv = random_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($method));
    $options = 0;
    $key = hash("sha256", $key);
    return openssl_encrypt($string, $method, $key, $options, $iv);
}

function decrypt($string, $key)
{
    $method = "BF-CBC";
    $iv = random_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($method));
    $options = 0;
    $key = hash("sha256", $key);
    return openssl_decrypt($string, $method, $key, $options, $iv);
}
```

Using these 2 functions for encrypting and decrypting data, only my encrypting works.

```php
// Encrypting foo 
echo encrypt("foo", "hfgdhgdfhgfd");

// Response
DyUxPwraJyk=

// Decrypting DyUxPwraJyk= 
echo decrypt("DyUxPwraJyk=", "hfgdhgdfhgfd");

// Doesn't respond with anything.
```

I have tried everything, even rewriting the functions multiple times but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I could be wrong, but doesn't $iv need to be the same for the encryption and decryption of a particular string, rather than random both times?

Comment: @IMSoP, you are correct, the IV acts in a manner similar to salt and can be [stored](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/12076) or even transmitted since it isn’t secret.

Comment: Why did I not think of that? Thank you so much!

Comment: @IMSoP please post your comment as an answer, so it can be approved

Comment: @CasparV. Yes, I didn't have the ability to check the details when I wrote that comment; I have now, so have posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$iv` option there is the "Initialization Vector", which acts sort of like a salt: it provides a different initial state for each message so that encrypting the same message twice is guaranteed to give different results.

Like a salt, the IV should be chosen randomly when *encrypting* the message, and then transmitted or stored along with the message, so that when *decrypting* the message you can provide the same value.

Probably you want your `encrypt` function to append `$iv` to the output, and `decrypt` to separate them back out.

```
function encrypt($string, $key)
{
    $method = "BF-CBC";
    $iv = random_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($method));
    $options = 0;
    $key = hash("sha256", $key);
    return base64_encode($iv)
        . '|'
        . openssl_encrypt($string, $method, $key, $options, $iv);
}

function decrypt($encryptedString, $key)
{
    $method = "BF-CBC";
    [ $iv, $ciphertext ] = explode('|', $encryptedString, 2);
    $iv = base64_decode($iv);
    $options = 0;
    $key = hash("sha256", $key);
    return openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $method, $key, $options, $iv);
}

echo encrypt("foo", "hfgdhgdfhgfd");
# fJTTArVw8e8=|zJOHacxbs1Q=

echo decrypt("fJTTArVw8e8=|zJOHacxbs1Q=", "hfgdhgdfhgfd");
# foo
```